# Open app in specific view when user taps on push notification with iOS 13 Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11

My app allows remote push notifications to a user. How do I enable it to be opened in a specific view controller when the user taps on the push notification? I want the app to open and navigate to a specific view controller depending on the push notification received.

Comment: Follow this tutorial https://fluffy.es/perform-action-notification-tap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to check when your app is on close state using launch option in " func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool{ :

```
 if let option = launchOptions {
    let info = option[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]
         if (info != nil) {
            self.goAnotherVC()
     }
}
```

and in view did load in your landing VC set the observer

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.goToVc(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue:identifier), object: nil)
```

Selector Method :

```
 @objc func goToVc(notification:Notification) {
     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"landingVC") as! landingVC
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)  
}
```

In app delegate :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name(identifier), object: userInfo)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for iOS 13+

In AppDelegae :

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
   
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(identifier), object: nil)
        completionHandler()
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` of Landing `ViewController` :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showChatController(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "noti"), object: nil)    
}
```

In your landing `viewController` add following selector method :

```
@objc
func showChatController(notification: Notification) {
print("DEBUG: show chat controller here..")
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a **notification** once you receive and the user clicks on the notification.

Along with the notification, you can pass the value which will later used to identify to which view controller you need to navigate.

Create a class which will be responsible for all the push notification navigation handling. You can name it like **PushNotificationHandler**. Let the PushNotificationHandler handler take care of all the logic to navigate to the view controllers.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool { 
}
```

- Get the value from the deep link using the above delegate method
- Trigger a notification with the value
- Handle the notification inside **PushNotificationHandler** class

Comment: The above method won't be called if the user has already launched the app and app is now running in the background.